# Iron:router "globbing" isn't working

Tags: meteor, iron-router, glob

I want to be able to match paths like this:
`/path/anything/goes/here/and/can/be/an/arbitrarily/long/path`.

So I tried all of the following:

```
Router.route('/path/*', function(){
    this.render('home');
});
```

I also tried the path: `'/path/:something(*)'` and I also tried specifying the path in the second argument `options` object to `Router.route`: `{path: '/path/*', action:myActionFunction}` along with an action function. I even tried using `Router.map` instead of `Router.route`, as prescribed in both of the following:

https://gentlenode.com/journal/meteor-11-iron-router-cheatsheet/18
http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/iron-router-tutorial

But still, going to the `/path/anything/goes/here` doesn't work. It takes me to the default iron:router error page:

> > > > > > Oops, looks like there's no route on the client or the server for url: "http... localhost:1710... /path/this/should/work/according/to/the/above/links."

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`'/(.*)'`

or

`'/path/(.*)'`

if the url really is domain.com/path/

I serve routes from '/(.*)' via look up on a collection of documents from this.params

If you need any routes prior to a catchall put the catchall route in a Meteor.startup and have your finely grained defined routes prior in your router file client side.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I see what you did there! I modified your solution a bit to fit my situation. It's really odd because every resource I checked omits the decimal point. Then I realized that was just turned into a regex...

I used: `'/path/([_]?[a-zA-Z0-9]*)*'`

since I only wanted to match alnums (and an optional leading underscore) Thanks, you helped me out a bunch!!

Comment: are you sure about your second statement? If the catchall is in startup, won't it catch everything before they get a chance to be seen by the fine-grained routes? I thought Meteor.startup is run before router.js?

Comment: @Clover No I am not sure about the 2nd statement.  What I do know is that when my glob ( or optional ) route was not in the startup it was running before routes in packages.  tmeasday suggested putting the blog/optional route in startup to prevent that behavior.  See this issue #: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/1007